# Age calculation glitch with decimal place

Tags: mysql, filemaker

We have the syntax below to calculate age with year followed by 2 decimal places. The formula works, except when the birthday is a whole year (10 years, 0 months; 10.0). The issue is that the decimal place shifts to the right for whole years without any months. A one year old would show up as 10.0, a 9 year old would show up as 90.0. Any guidance in the script to fix this glitch would be appreciated!

```
Year ( GetAsNumber ( DOE )) - Year ( DOB ) - If ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) < Date ( Month ( DOB ) ; Day ( DOB ) ; Year ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) ) ); 1 ; 0 ) & ( Mod ( Month ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) ) - Month ( DOB ) + 12 - If ( Day ( GetAsNumber ( DOE ) ) < Day ( DOB ) ; 1 ; 0 ) ; 12 ) / 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your approach is that you are using the text operator `&` when you should be using the numeric `+` operator.

Thus when the `Mod()` function returns a zero (i.e. when the interval is a whole number of years), you are appending a string value of `"0"` to the result.

I would also suggest you simplify the calculation to:

```
Let ( 
elapsedMonths = 12 * ( Year ( DOE ) - Year ( DOB ) ) + Month ( DOE ) - Month ( DOB ) - ( Day ( DOE ) < Day ( DOB ) ) 
;
Div ( elapsedMonths ; 12 ) + Mod ( elapsedMonths ; 12 ) / 12
)
```

The result of this calculation is a number. To display the number with two decimal places, format the field as Decimal and select the *'Fixed number of decimals'* option.

---

**P.S.** Note that the `Year()`, `Month()` and `Day()` functions require a *date* as the parameter. When you do:

```
Year ( GetAsNumber ( DOB ))
```

FileMaker will execute it as:

```
Year ( GetAsDate ( GetAsNumber ( DOB )))
```

And since `DOB` is (presumably) a date to begin with, you're only compounding unnecessary type conversions, when you should have been using simply:

```
Year ( DOB )
```